# Is there a way a widget can catch UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate? SWIFT

Tags: swift, push-notification, widget

## Please help

[image]

### UserNotifications

```
Import UserNotifications
```

put this in viewDidLoad

```
func setupNotif() {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options [.alert,.sound]) {
        (granted, error) in
      }

      let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      notificationContent.title = "Push Invitation"
      notificationContent.subtitle = "Push subtitle"
      notificationContent.body = "Please check notif"
      notificationContent.sound = .default
      notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = categoryIdentifier

      let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false)
        
      let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "SampleNotif", content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() 
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest) {(error) in if (error != nil) {} else { }}
 }
```

this is the delegate for UUNotification center

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent  notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
 }
 
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
 }
```

Comment: let action1 = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "tapAction1",title: "Tap me later", options: [.init(rawValue: 0)])
                        let action2 = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "tapAction1",title: "Tap me now", options: [.foreground])
                        let action3 = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "decline", title: "Decline", options: [])

Comment: Please edit your question and describe your problem better so people can help you.

Comment: @Hassan, the title says all.. i need the widget to catch pushnotification action.. it is only working on the app...

Answer (score 0):

**My answer, there is no way to do that.. as per apple.. i think this question might pop up in the future..

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
open class UNUserNotificationCenter : NSObject {

```
// The delegate can only be set from an application
weak open var delegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate?
```